# Unit testing async/await javascript with mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Hey guys so I am currently working on this async function and writing unit test for this but it is not working it says `AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Everytime I think of coding, I am happy'` this is my code for the function:

```
async function funcFour() {// async automatically returns a promise
let result = new Promise((resolve) => {// returns a new promise named result
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(`Everytime I think of coding, I am happy`);//resolve happens after three seconds
    }, 1500)
});
const response = await result;//closing resolve of new promise
console.log(response);//console.logging response of new promise
```

`} funcFour();`

And here is my unit test for it:

```
describe("flirtFour()", () => {
it("Should return Everytime I think of coding, I am happy", async function () {
    return flirtFour().then(result => {
        expect(result).to.equal("Everytime I think of coding, I am happy")

    })
    

})
```

`})`

This is the first time I write unit test and I am trying to do it with async func so I am new to it. I really want to see how this is done so Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Avoid using arrow functions inside mocha tests https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

Answer (score 1):

Although you have given `funcFour()` above and trying to test `flirtFour()` below, I am assuming they are the same. Now `flirtFour()` doesn't return anything as of now. You need to return the `response` from that function. By default, the returned value is `undefined`. Also remember that whatever you **return** from the `async` function gets wrapped into a Promise itself. So you're actually returning a **Promise** like so :-

`return Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

If you simply return `response` that will automatically be treated as

`return Promise.resolve(response)`

which is probably what you need.

So change your `funcFour()` to the following :-

```
async function funcFour() {// async automatically returns a promise
let result = new Promise((resolve) => {// returns a new promise named result
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(`Everytime I think of coding, I am happy`);//resolve happens after three seconds
    }, 1500)
});
const response = await result;
return response;
}
```